# 2d-RandomWalks with N steps and fixed distance between first and last point

Tags: random

community,
I'm trying to figure out a way how to create a 2d list simulating a N-Step-Randomwalk with a fixed distance between first and last point. I already got the RandomWalk with the step size 1:

Input:

RW2D[n_] := 
 Accumulate[Through[{Cos, Sin}[#]] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 2 [Pi]}, n]]

I have no idea how to connect the first and the last point.
I'd be happy to receive some help.
Thanks alot
Greetings.

Comment: Why not use standard features like `RandomFunction[RandomWalkProcess[0.5], {0, 10^3}, 2]`?

Comment: I'm relatively new to this software so i find it easier to have the points in a list.

Comment: Sorry, did not notice that you are walking in a circle. This is 1D and not 2D.

Comment: But it turns out 2D. I fixed your typo `RW2D[n_] := 
 Accumulate[Through[{Cos, Sin}[#]] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}, n]]; ListLinePlot[RW2D[100]]`

Answer (score 2):

```
RW2D[n_] := 
 Accumulate[Through[{Cos, Sin}[#]] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}, n]]
Table[ListLinePlot[RW2D[n], PlotLabel -> Row[{"n=", n}]], {n, {10, 100, 1000}}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Oh right thanks, i got this now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Graph method where you set the random walk start point, the end point, and the number of steps in between. It computes all possible paths and random pick one, therefore it makes sense only for small grids and number of steps

[image]